# Spring hibernate JPA project injecting older version of dependencies in WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring gradle project . The dependencies are as follows:

```
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'de.grundid.opendatalab:geojson-jackson:1.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile ('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0+'){
            exclude module:'tomcat-servlet-api'

    }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2+'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.12'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.6.12' 

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5+"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5+"    
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5+" 

    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1+'

    compile 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2+'
    compile 'org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2+'

    compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:2+'
```

Somehow while deploying this project to tomcat server , older version of spring dependencies are being injected aswell . The snapshot of the lib folder of the deployed project is

[image]

What exactly am I missing? Any suggestion would be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same, but there is no old version of dependencies injected. Try to clean your project and rebuild it.
[image: Gradle test project]